# Discord.py random image to send to ctx.message.channel

Tags: python-3.x, random, discord.py

So i'm trying to make a lil piece of code that
sends a random image from a folder
im using discord.py
i dunno how to do it
so i thought stackoverflow could help me!
i'm sorry guys but i'm actually kinda new to python coding
and i really suck

Comment: Hi there, this is a website for coding help rather than code writing. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

to send images with discord.py you use

```py
await channel.send(file=discord.File('my_file.png'))
```

If you want to send a random image, you could save every filename to a list and on a command send a random file from that list:

```
import random

files = ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png']

@bot.command()
async def image(ctx):
    file = random.choice(files)
    await channel.send(file=discord.File(file))
```

if you want to automatically add every image file in the same directory as the .py file the bot is running from, you can use the [os module](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/os-module-python-examples/):

```py
import os

files = []
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith('.png'):
        files.append(file)
```